# Missing AddWithValue from DbCommand.Parameters

Tags: sql, ado.net

I am building an sqlwrapper to handle both MSsql and Sqlite, I have no issues using the generic dbconnection, dataset and dataadapter so far, but with dbcommand parameters.add is the only option.  I'd like to use parameter.addwithvalue like sqlcommand and sqlitecommand have, but I am unsure how to implement it.

For example here is my sqlitefactory:

```
public class SqlLiteFactory : SqlFactory
{
    public override DbConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        return new SQLiteConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ClientDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        //return new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Resources\\qaqc.sqlite;Version=3");
    }

    public override DataAdapter CreateAdapter(string command, DbConnection connection)
    {
        return new SQLiteDataAdapter(command, connection as SQLiteConnection);
    }

    public override DbCommand CreateCommand()
    {
        return new SQLiteCommand();
    }
}
```

Here is my implementation:

```
DbConnection c = SqlHandler.Instance.CreateConnection();

DbCommand cmd = SqlHandler.Instance.CreateCommand();

cmd.Connection = c;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT column FROM table WHERE syncstatus = 0 and UserName = @user GROUP BY column;";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@user");
cmd.Parameters["@user"].Value = SystemInformation.UserName;
DbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

in the more specific sqlcommand and sqlitecommand there is a method .addwithvalue() which is what I'd like to have in the parent dbcommand class.

Comment: Added some code examples.

Comment: You are using DbCommand, Have you tried with SqlCommand instead?

Comment: well I am using dbcommand because I need to pass it to either a sqlcommand or a sqlite command, I am not sure if passing a sqlcommand to a sqlitecommand would work.

Comment: You are using baseclass, and you are looking for method implemented at derived class (sqlcommand or a sqlite command ) in base class.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Solved it with and extension method

```
static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static void AddParameterWithValue(this DbCommand command, string parameterName, object parameterValue)
        {
            var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
            parameter.ParameterName = parameterName;
            parameter.Value = parameterValue;
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        }
    }
```

from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d56a4710-3fd1-4039-a0d9-c4c6bd1cd22e/dbcommand-parameters-collection-missing-addwithvalue-method

Comment: Nice! To make it even more generic one can replace DbCommand with the interface IDbCommand.