# Variable 'SDA' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i am actually having a problem about this, can you please help me out?
i'm still a beginner and i don't know how to fix this...

```
Private Sub textSearch_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles textSearch.TextChanged

    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString =
    "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=student_info"

    Dim SDA As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
    Dim DV As New DataView(dbDataSet)
    Dim bsource As New BindingSource
    Dim Query As String
    Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Try
        Query = "select * from std_info where firstname like ' % " & textSearch.Text & " % '"
        SDA.Fill(ds)
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
        bsource.DataSource = dbDataSet
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bsource
        SDA.Update(dbDataSet)
        MysqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: how is this possibly related to Java?

Comment: The first thing you should know is that name of language that you are using, you have tagged all other languages except the one that you are using. So I would like to remind you that you are using `VB.Net`

Comment: For your 2nd question about not getting any results, you have extra spaces in your SELECT query.  I would also suggest you learn to use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection vulnerability.  Here's a good article on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608362/missing-addwithvalue-from-dbcommand-parameters

Answer (score 1):

Well the error occurs because you have declared it

```
Dim SDA As MySqlDataAdapter
```

but not instantiated (i.e. set it to an instance of an object) it before you call

```
SDA.Fill(ds)
```

I have no idea of what exactly your code is doing as I've never used MySQL etc. but at least try something like

```
Query = "select * from std_info where firstname like ' % " & textSearch.Text & " % '"
COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
SDA = new MySqlDataAdapter(COMMAND)
SDA.Fill(ds)
```

The fact that `ds` is an empty new `DataSet` worries me a little but that could just be my ignorance of MySQL classes.

Comment: thanks it kinda help, ds is a typo-error and i'm sorry for that. my only problem now is that when I try to search data no result are shown. how can I do this?

Comment: I'm afraid apart from the instantiation issue I have no familiarity with all those classes (`DataSet`, `DataView`, `DataTable`, `BindingSource` etc.)

Comment: i am using visual basic studio

Answer (score 0):

I already run the program, the only thing is that I still cannot see the data in the table and show it to the datagridview, and also when I try to search no results are shown... help? (i am just a beginner don't be angry at me pls.)

Private Sub textSearch_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles textSearch.TextChanged

```
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString =
    "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=student_info"

    Dim Query As String
    Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand
    Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
    Dim DV As New DataView(dbDataSet)
    Dim bsource As New BindingSource



    Try

        Query = "select * from std_info where firstname like ' % " & textSearch.Text & " % '"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
        SDA = New MySqlDataAdapter(COMMAND)
        SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
        bsource.DataSource = dbDataSet
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bsource
        SDA.Update(dbDataSet)

        MysqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not an answer.  Please _edit_ your question by clicking the edit link and add this information to your original question, then delete this answer.